# Is a Noetherian normal local domain (universally) catenary?

Tags: commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Let $R$ be a ring. Then $R$ is $\textit{catenary}$ if for a pair of prime ideal $p \subseteq q$, all maximal chains of prime ideals $p = p_0 \subseteq p_1 \subseteq \dots \subseteq p_n = q$ have the same length.

For details and properties, please refer to http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00NH.

Since a Cohen-Macaulay ring is universally catenary, algebras which are essentially of finite type over such ring is again catenary. For me, it is hard to find a non catenary ring, but at the same time not every ring is catenary. I would like to know some good rings are catenary or not.

> Is a Noetherian normal local domain $R$ catenary?

Of course, the answer is positive if $\dim R \le 2$ (then it is Cohen-Macaulay) or $R$ is complete (by the Cohen structure theorem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a counter-example due to Ogoma in ["Non-catenary pseudo-geometric normal rings"](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/math1924/6/1/6_1_147/_article), which seems to be a modification of one of Nagata's examples of a non-catenary ring. Heitmann has a simpler description of the construction in ["A non-catenary, normal, local domain"](http://doi.org/doi:10.1216/RMJ-1982-12-1-145), as does Lech in ["Yet another proof of a result of Ogoma"](http://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0075464).